# Meditation vs auto reflex in body

Tags: meditation, automaticity

I was trig the zen breathing meditation technique similar to [this](https://www.medicalnewstoday.com/articles/324417) post instructions.

so i have seen some auto reflex in my mouth like Swallowing reflex, also before have seen some tedx speech which at some part of it the speaker was saying about some auto reflex in 
 focusing to some partly upper of Direct line of us sight meditation !! and interpreted it as a gear change of car driver ( driver comes to body and gear change comes to auto reflex), so i like to know more about it and google the [meditation auto reflex in body](https://www.google.com/search?q=meditation%20auto%20reflex%20in%20body&oq=meditation%20auto%20reflex%20in%20body%20&aqs=chrome..69i57j33.15648j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) but don't find any direct link to it, so i don't know is this popular in meditation.

I was thinking to work on it if it is common as one of my class project (‌research methodology  course's project), so is there any scientific text about this phenomena in psychology, any tag for search or paper or ...

Thanks.